# Remove negative values from a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, plotly

I downloaded some recent earthquake data for visualizing, and I am getting error:

> ValueError:
> Invalid element(s) received for the 'size' property of scattergeo.marker
> Invalid elements include: [-0.55, -0.44999999999999996, -0.15, -0.5, -1.5, -0.6, -0.75, -1.9500000000000002, -1.85, -1.5]

```
The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
  - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
  - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
```

How do I remove the negative elements from the JSON file that I'm using?

here is my code:

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Layout
from plotly import offline

# Explore the structure of the data.
filename = "data/7_day_eq.json"
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

# Create a file that is more readable.
readable_file = "data/readable_7_day_eq_data.json"
with open(readable_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)

# Take all the information from features key.
all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']

# Get all the magnitudes.
mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
for eq_dicts in all_eq_dicts:
    mags.append(eq_dicts['properties']['mag'])
    lons.append(eq_dicts['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    lats.append(eq_dicts['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
    hover_texts.append(eq_dicts['properties']['title'])

# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
layout_title = all_eq_data['metadata']['title']
my_layout = Layout(title=f'Global Earthquakes{layout_title}')

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes_7_days.html')
```

The data for my "7_day_eq.json"  came from https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php Past 7 days section and copied all earthquakes into a file.

Comment: Looks like the negatives are coming from the coordinates.  Are you sure you want them out? Do you want to remove those negative elements i.e. replace them with 0 or just convert them to positive values by removing negative sign?

Comment: Knowing how to both convert to 0 and make them positive values would be helpful. Or whichever is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use the absolute value, to make all of the values positive

```py
# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [abs(5*mag) for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
```

or if you don't want to make them positive, but just 0 a simple if will do that

```py
# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag if mag > 0 else 0.1 for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
```

I used 0.1 there as the error message

```py
The 'size' property is a number and may be specified as:
  - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]
  - A tuple, list, or one-dimensional numpy array of the above
```

suggests, that the interval is open, meaning you can't use 0

Comment: Thank you, abs() was a simple fix and sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make 2 separate mags lists depending of whether you want it as positives or 0 replaced as below and it should work

```
mags_zero_replaced = [mag if mag > 0 else 0 for mag in mags]
mags_postive_converted = [abs(mag) for mag in mags]

data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag for mag in mags_zero_replaced],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
```